# Remove empty parts of an object in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a nested object using Angular 7 and want to remove the empty parts:

```
carrier:{
   name:'',
   street:null,
   zip:'zip',
   city:'city',
   country:'XY',
   contactPerson:{
      name:null,
      phoneNo:null,
      emailAddr:null
   }
},
timeSlotOrders:[
   {
      loadType:'blabla',
      moveIn:{
         date:moment(this.timeslotForm.controls.moveInDate.value).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
         time:this.timeslotForm.controls.moveInTime.value,
         serviceType:this.timeslotForm.controls.moveInLoadingService.value,
         addInfo:this.timeslotForm.controls.moveInRemark.value,
         service:this.timeslotForm.controls.moveInService.value,

      }      
      nr:0
   },
   ...
```

Other Javascript solutions I found here do not work for me here, because I can't call removeEmpty() in removeEmpty() somehow:

```
function removeEmpty(obj) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    if (obj[key] == null || (Array.isArray(obj[key]) && obj[key].length === 0)) {
      delete obj[key];
    } else if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
      removeEmpty(obj[key]);
    }
  });
  return obj;
};
```

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: What do you mean *"can't call ... somehow"*? Give a [mcve].

Comment: The above function does not work in Angular. First, it complains about the function keyword. If I replace 'function' to 'public', it says removeEmpty() cannot be found.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to put it inside a class, in which case you need to treat it as a method, not a function. Or just move it *outside the class*. This is nothing to do with Angular.

Comment: Thank you, moving it outside the class worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example with your `carrier` variable. Your code does not seem to remove the empty object.

```js
var carrier = {
  name: '',
  street: null,
  zip: 'zip',
  city: 'city',
  country: 'XY',
  contactPerson: {
    name: null,
    phoneNo: null,
    emailAddr: null,
  }
};

const removeEmpty = (obj) => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    if (obj[key] == null) {
      delete obj[key];
    } else if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
      removeEmpty(obj[key]);
      // Check if object is empty
      if (Object.entries(obj[key]).length === 0 && obj[key].constructor === Object) {
        delete obj[key];
      }
    }
  });

  return obj;
}

removeEmpty(carrier);
console.log(carrier);
```